# Function to find if a value comes before another value in excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqA4s.png)

How can I know if a value comes before another value in a row in excel?
For e.g. I want to know name of persons who have value "EL" before value "CL".

Comment: **within a single cell or in multiple cells ??**

Answer (score 0):

For a string in cell **A1**, the following formula will return the string if "EL" comes before "CL". Otherwise it will return an empty string "". Note that this formula is case-sensitive

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("EL",A1)<FIND("CL",A1),FALSE),A1,"")
```

for the non case-sensitive alternative, use the `UPPER()` function as below:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("EL",UPPER(A1))<FIND("CL",UPPER(A1)),FALSE),A1,"")
```